# Loop through associative array of associative arrays using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
$students = array(
    'rishab' => array(
        'age' =>25 ,
        'marks' =>400,
        'class' =>'MCA'
     ), 
     'kamran' => array(
        'age' =>23 ,
        'marks' =>550,
        'class' =>'MBA'
     ),
     'Sunil'  => array(
         'age' =>23 ,
         'marks' =>550,
         'class' =>'MBA'
     )
);
```

how can i loop through this php associative array using foreach loop??

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815511/foreach-loop-over-multidimensional-associative-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a double foreach to loop all values of all sub arrays.

```
foreach($students as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Key: '.$key.'<br />';
    foreach($value as $s_key => $s_value) {
        echo 'Sub key: '.$s_key.' => '.$s_value.'<br />';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Result:

```
Key: rishab
Sub key: age => 25
Sub key: marks => 400
Sub key: class => MCA

Key: kamran
Sub key: age => 23
Sub key: marks => 550
Sub key: class => MBA

Key: Sunil
Sub key: age => 23
Sub key: marks => 550
Sub key: class => MBA
```

Comment: what if query return id and name how to loop through so the id and name can settle in one `<td value = "id">name</td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $students as $name=>$student){
    print $name . ":" . $student["class"] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

will output this

```
rishab:MCA
kamran:MBA
Sunil:MBA
```

Comment: what if query return id and name how to loop through so the id and name can settle in one `<td value = "id">name</td>`

Comment: what if query return id and name how to loop through so the id and name can settle in one `<td value = "id">name</td>`